# Submitting a Post to API from Flutter app always returning Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: python, flutter, dart

I have the following API in a Django project where I am trying to send a log with some variables that are Int and String.

Here is the Api/views.py:

```
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def addlog(request,username, id):
    workout = Workout.objects.get(id=id, user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if workout.active:
            active_session = ActiveSession.objects.get(id=ActiveSession.objects.last().id)
            form = LogForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                data = Log()
                data.user = request.user
                data.log_workout = request.POST.get('log_workout')
                data.log_exercise = request.POST.get('log_exercise')
                data.log_order = request.POST.get('log_order')
                data.log_repetitions = form.cleaned_data['log_repetitions']
                data.log_weight = form.cleaned_data['log_weight']
                data.workout_id = Workout.pk
                data.save()
```

In my flutter app I have created the api_service.dart as following:

```
  static Future<http.Response> addLog(int logWeight, int logRepetitions,
      int logOrder, String logExercise, String logWorkout, int id) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(Config.apiURL +
        Config.userAddlogAPI.replaceFirst("{id}", id.toString()));
    try {
      final response = await http.post(url, headers: {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
            'Token xxxxxxxxxxxx',
      }, body: {
        'log_weight': logWeight,
        'log_repetitions': logRepetitions,
        'log_order': logOrder,
        'log_exercise': logExercise,
        'log_workout': logWorkout,
      });
     #.......if to catch error but it doesn't reach this part........................
  }
```

Here the screen.dart

```
 Form(
    child: Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(keyboardType:TextInputType.number,
            onChanged:(value) {final int?parsedValue = int.tryParse(value);
              if (parsedValue !=null) {setState(() { logWeight = parsedValue;});
              } else {}
            },),
          TextFormField(keyboardType:TextInputType.number,
            onChanged:(value) {
              final int?parsedValue = int.tryParse(value);
              if (parsedValue != null) {setState(() {logRepetitions = parsedValue;});
              } else {}},),
          OutlinedButton(child: Text('Add Log'),
            onPressed:
                () async {
              final Map<String, dynamic> arguments = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
              final int id = arguments['id'] ??0;
              final String logWorkout = arguments['logWorkout'] ??'';
              final String logExercise = snapshot.data![index].name; // <-- set logExercise here
              final int logOrder = breakdown.order;
              print("$logRepetitions, $logWeight, $logOrder, $logExercise, $logWorkout, $id");
              print(id.runtimeType); 
              try {
                final http.Response response = await APIService.addLog(
                    logWeight, logRepetitions, logOrder, logExercise, logWorkout, id);
                if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                  print('Log submitted successfully');} else {
                  print('Failed to submit log');}
              } catch (error) { print(error);
                await showDialog( context: context, builder: (context) {
                    return AlertDialog(title:Text('Error'),
                      content: Text(error.toString()),
                      actions: [ OutlinedButton(
                          child: Text('OK'),
                          onPressed: () {Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },),],); },); } }, ), ],),),),
```

So in the dart file there are 2 textfields and an outline button inside a form. The textfields are where users add their inputs in numeric values and when the user clicks on the submit I receive this error. I have made sure that the only 2 strings which are `logExercise, logWorkout` are actually strings. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and how to fix it. I am fairly new to flutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your `int` variables to `String` to use them inside
`http` `body`

> Sends an HTTP POST request with the given headers and body to the
> given URL.  `body` sets the body of the request. It can be a `String`,
> a `List<int>` or  a `Map<String, String>`. If it's a `String`, it's
> encoded using [encoding] and  used as the body of the request. The
> content-type of the request will  default to "text/plain".
>
> If `body` is a `List`, it's used as a list of bytes for the body of the
> request.
>
> If `body` is a `Map`, it's encoded as form fields using [encoding]. The
> content-type of the request will be set to
> `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`; this cannot be overridden.
>
> encoding defaults to utf8.

Answer (score 0):

Before all please put all static value to check if this work or not then check below.

```
 final http.Response response = await APIService.addLog(
                    logWeight, logRepetitions, logOrder, logExercise, logWorkout, id);
```

```
TextFormField(keyboardType:TextInputType.number,onChanged:(value) {
              final int?parsedValue = int.parse(value == '' ? '0' : value);  /// Here Please use this
              if (parsedValue != null) {
                 setState(() {
                 logRepetitions = parsedValue;
                 });
                 } else {

                   }
                },),
```

and Also Runtime datatype all variables.

```
print("$logRepetitions, $logWeight, $logOrder, $logExercise, $logWorkout, $id");
```